# What's the idiomatic solution to embarassingly parallel tasks in Go?

Tags: go, concurrency, channel, goroutine

I'm currently staring at a beefed up version of the following code:

```
func embarrassing(data []string) []string {
  resultChan := make(chan string)
  var waitGroup sync.WaitGroup
  for _, item := range data {
    waitGroup.Add(1)
    go func(item string) {
      defer waitGroup.Done()
      resultChan <- doWork(item)
    }(item)
  }

  go func() {
    waitGroup.Wait()
    close(resultChan)
  }()

  var results []string
  for result := range resultChan {
    results = append(results, result)
  }
  return results
}
```

This is just blowing my mind. All this is doing can be expressed in other languages as

```
results = parallelMap(data, doWork)
```

Even if it can't be done quite this easily in Go, isn't there still a better way than the above?

Comment: Whether your parallel map is actually faster or not than a sequential one depends on a lot of factors. Unbound parallelism typically is not a good idea.

Answer (score 10):

If you need all the results, you don't need the channel (and the extra goroutine to close it) to communicate the results, you can write directly into the results slice:

```
func cleaner(data []string) []string {
    results := make([]string, len(data))

    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(len(data))
    for i, item := range data {
        go func(i int, item string) {
            defer wg.Done()
            results[i] = doWork(item)
        }(i, item)
    }
    wg.Wait()

    return results
}
```

This is possible because slice elements act as distinct variables, and thus can be written individually without synchronization. For details, see [Can I concurrently write different slice elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49879322/can-i-concurrently-write-different-slice-elements/49879469#49879469). You also get the results in the same order as your input for free.

Anoter variation: if `doWork()` would not return the result but get the address where the result should be "placed", and additionally the `sync.WaitGroup` to signal completion, that `doWork()` function could be executed "directly" as a new goroutine.

We can create a reusable wrapper for `doWork()`:

```
func doWork2(item string, result *string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    *result = doWork(item)
}
```

If you have the processing logic in such format, this is how it can be executed concurrently:

```
func cleanest(data []string) []string {
    results := make([]string, len(data))

    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(len(data))
    for i, item := range data {
        go doWork2(item, &results[i], wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()

    return results
}
```

Yet another variation could be to pass a channel to `doWork()` on which it is supposed to deliver the result. This solution doesn't even require a `sync.Waitgroup`, as we know how many elements we want to receive from the channel:

```
func cleanest2(data []string) []string {
    ch := make(chan string)
    for _, item := range data {
        go doWork3(item, ch)
    }

    results := make([]string, len(data))
    for i := range results {
        results[i] = <-ch
    }
    return results
}

func doWork3(item string, res chan<- string) {
    res <- "done:" + item
}
```

"Weakness" of this last solution is that it may collect the result "out-of-order" (which may or may not be a problem). This approach can be improved to retain order by letting `doWork()` receive and return the index of the item. For details and examples, see [How to collect values from N goroutines executed in a specific order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37856337/how-to-collect-values-from-n-goroutines-executed-in-a-specific-order/37857863#37857863)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use reflection to achieve something similar.

In this example it distribute the handler function over 4 goroutines and returns the results in a new instance of the given source slice type.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "strings"
    "sync"
)

func parralelMap(some interface{}, handle interface{}) interface{} {
    rSlice := reflect.ValueOf(some)
    rFn := reflect.ValueOf(handle)
    dChan := make(chan reflect.Value, 4)
    rChan := make(chan []reflect.Value, 4)
    var waitGroup sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
        waitGroup.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer waitGroup.Done()
            for v := range dChan {
                rChan <- rFn.Call([]reflect.Value{v})
            }
        }()
    }
    nSlice := reflect.MakeSlice(rSlice.Type(), rSlice.Len(), rSlice.Cap())
    for i := 0; i < rSlice.Len(); i++ {
        dChan <- rSlice.Index(i)
    }
    close(dChan)
    go func() {
        waitGroup.Wait()
        close(rChan)
    }()
    i := 0
    for v := range rChan {
        nSlice.Index(i).Set(v[0])
        i++
    }
    return nSlice.Interface()
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(
        parralelMap([]string{"what", "ever"}, strings.ToUpper),
    )
}
```

Test here https://play.golang.org/p/iUPHqswx8iS